# File name is creating with space in perl?

Tags: perl

in perl scripting i am giving name of a file as input to create a file in my folder. I have written following code for that but the thing is its creating extra space between filename and its extension like myfile .txt  How to slve this??
code is

```
print"file name=";
$file=<STDIN>;
open($f, "+>>$file.txt") or die "Couldn't open file $file.txt, $!";
```

Input: `myfile`

Output:

in current folder am seeing `myfile .txt` instead of `myfile.txt`

what is the solution for this???

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: And don't forget to `chomp`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove the linefeed at the end of your line:

Try:

```
print"file name=";
$file=<STDIN>;
chomp $file;
open($f, "+>>$file.txt") or die "Couldn't open file $file.txt, $!";
```

Comment: There is no carriage-return. Perl standardises input across all platforms so that the line separator always appears as `"\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line break with [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
my $file = <STDIN>;
chomp $file;
```

Comment: Or, in a single statement, `chomp(my $file = <STDIN>)`

Answer (score -1):

Whenever to give an input from user, perl will append a \n character at the end of the input. To avoid that we need to use the "chomp" keyword. This removes the \n character at the end.

```
chomp($file);
```

Comment: It is a line feed that is appended "\n".  Not a space " "